# French styles for negative statements

Tags: grammaire, négation

Can someone explain the meanings and differences among the following:

- n'est pas
- n'est-ce pas
- ce n'est pas
- C'est pas

Are they equal and are differences about formal and informal speech?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La négation ***ne** ... **pas*** encadre le verbe :

- Ce **n'** est **pas** encore huit heures.
- Il **n'** est **pas** content.

En langage familier, surtout à l'oral, il arrive qu'on omette le **ne**. Il est conseillé de ne pas faire ça à l'écrit, sauf si on veut imiter le langage parlé :

- C'est **pas** encore huit heures.
- Il  est **pas** content.

Dans ***n'est-ce pas*** l'inversion du verbe *est* et du sujet *ce* indique que nous sommes en présence d'une question :

- **N'est-ce pas** trop tard pour aller au cinéma ce soir ?

*N'est-ce pas* peut aussi être utilisé :

- en fin de phrase affirmative, pour indiquer qu'en fait ce qu'on pose une question et qu'on attend la réaction de son interlocuteur :

  > Il fait chaud aujourd'hui, n'est-ce pas ?
- Ou comme réponse pour approuver ce que quelqu'un vient de dire :

  > A :  Il fait chaud aujourd'hui.
  > B : N'est-ce pas.

---

The negation is in two parts :  ***ne*** before the verb, ***pas*** after the verb.

When *ne* is placed in front of a vowel sound we omit the letter « e » and *ne* becomes *n'*. (You can visit the wikipedia article on [French elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision_%28French%29) for more on this subject of elision.):

- Ce **n'** est **pas** encore huit heures.
- Il **n'** est **pas** content.

When speaking some people omit the ***ne*** (or ***n'***). It is very informal and should not be done in writing unless, of course, we want to imitate oral speech:

- C'est **pas** encore huit heures.
- Il  est **pas** content.

***N'est-ce pas*** is found in questions : the verb is placed before the subject.

- **N'est-ce pas** trop tard pour aller au cinéma ce soir ?

***N'est-ce pas*** can be used as a stand alone expression:

- at the end of an affirmative statement to show we are asking a question and expecting a yes/no answer on the part of the person we are talking to:

  > Il fait chaud aujourd'hui, n'est-ce pas ?
- as an answer to approve something we've just been told:

  > A :  Il fait chaud aujourd'hui.
  > B : N'est-ce pas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I am not sure that the english version is the translation of the french version. Still I didn't get my answer. You say that `ne` should not be omitted. But the there is no `ne` in your examples. Also I didn't get the difference between the phrases. For example `ne/pa` and `ne/s/pa`

Comment: I've repeated the example sentences in the English text and explained about the ne/n'. Hope it's clearer now.